# Extracting a list from a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list which looks like this:

```
[["['  SHR RXX,0x3\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"],["['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"],["['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"]]
```

I want to convert it into a list that looks like this:

```
[['  SHR RXX,0x3\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n'],['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n'],['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you have lists in strings in that format? Where did the data come from originally and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: This should do the trick: `newlist = list(map(lambda x: eval(x[0]), oldlist))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate your strings as python syntax for each of your list elements.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> data = [["['  SHR RXX,0x3\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"],["['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"],["['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"]]
>>> [[literal_eval(i) for i in sub][0] for sub in data]
[['  SHR RXX,0x3\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\n'], ['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\n'], ['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\n']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy is needed. Just:

1. Remove the `'[` and `]'` at the start and end of each string with `[2:-2]`
2. Split the text at every `', '`
3. Run this through every element in the list with list comprehension

```py
l = [["['  SHR RXX,0x3\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"],["['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"],["['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']"]]
new_list = [x[0][2:-2].split("', '") for x in l]
```

output:

```
[['  SHR RXX,0x3\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n'],
 ['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n',
  '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n',
  '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n'],
 ['  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n', '  MOV RXX,qword ptr [RXX + 0x0]\\n']]
```

Comment: `[j.strip("[]'").split("', '") for i in l for j in i]`